# How to add definition modules?

Tags: python

I'm completing a task I was given by my Teacher and it asks for a modular program so I tried to create some `def` modules but I can't figure out how to pass parameters between them.

Here's the code so far. (I don't know how to make it much neater on the site sorry.)

```
import string

def Datawrite ():
    forename = []
    surname = []
    distance = []
    data = open("members.txt","r")
    for line in data:
        value = line.split(',')
        forename.append(value[0])
        surname.append(value[1])
        distance.append(value[2])
    data.close()

def FarthestWalker(distance):
    farthest_walk = distance[0]
    for counter in range(len(distance)):
        if float(distance[counter]) >= float(farthest_walk):
            farthest_walk = distance[counter]
            farthest_walk = float(farthest_walk)
            Calcandstore()

def Calcandstore(forename,surname,distance,farthest_walk):
    Results = open("Results.txt","w+")
    Results.write("The prize winnning memberes are:\n")
    seventy = 0.7*farthest_walk
    Winning = []
    for count in range(len(distance)):
        if float(distance[count]) >= float(seventy):
            Winning.append([count])
            for count in range(len(Winning)):
                Results.write(forename[count]+":")
                Results.write(surname[count]+":")
                Results.write(distance[count])
            Results.close()

Datawrite()
FarthestWalker(distance)
Calcandstore(forename,surname,distance,farthest_walk)
```

When I run the code it returns this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Assignment\Test.py", line 58, in <module>
    FarthestWalker(distance)
  File "E:\Assignment\Test.py", line 29, in FarthestWalker
    farthest_walk = distance[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have been tinkering with this for a few days now and I can't get the thing to work.

Comment: This code doesn't look like the one producing the error. You don't declare `distance` anywhere before calling `FarthestWalker(distance)`. If you have declared `distance = []` a name for an empty list for example, then `distance[0]` will cause an error as there are no values in the list.

Comment: You could declare  distance = [] outside of the functions

Comment: The 'def's aren't modules, they're called functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some issues:
1) `Datawrite` doesn't return anything so the lists you're building are lost in the ether.
2) You call `FarthestWalker` with distance which is never initialized.
3) You call `Calcandstore` with values that are not initialized.

To pass values from functions you need to return values and declare them. For example:

```
def make_cat():
    return 'Cat'

def print_animal(animal):
    print(animal)

c = make_cat()
print_animal(c)
```